# high power - overvoltage protection

Tags: circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection

I am designing a circuit to protect a load from over-voltage. The voltage at the load must be around 380VDC and the current consumption will be around 2A. In normal operation the Power Supply must increase the voltage as the load pulls more current so that the voltage drop across the cable is compensated.
However, if by any reason the power supply shoots the voltage to 800VDC, the circuit on the load must be opened, avoiding the load to see such a high voltage. The power supply is capable of delivering 8A.

I tried the circuit in the picture, it works pretty well as it opens at 400VDC (triggered by the two zeners in series). But at 500VDC the zeners blow up even with a 150k resistor.

Would a crowbar work in this situation ? I really don't want to use glass fuses to avoid opening the enclosure where the load is installed.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: A crowbar would blow probably blow a fuse _somewhere_... So I guess you'd have to open a box anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please Look at the following picture

https://eenews.cdnartwhere.eu/sites/default/files/images/01-edit-photo-uploads/2012/2012-03-march/linear-technology/fig-3a.jpg
inside the link
http://www.eenewsautomotive.com/content/high-voltage-surge-stoppers-ensure-reliable-operation-during-power-surges/page/0/1

A circuit based on LTC4366 with proper changes could do the job for you.
Moreover the circuit could make the output open by proper triggering the SD input.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, just had time now to go over it. I tried the LTC4366 and it works very well however there is still something I overlooked and is causing the mosfet to be damaged.

Comment: The circuit is very close to your limitations. the chip manufacturer must have proper recommendation for you but If you know the cause of the damage, there is always a way to add some components to prevent it.